# Can a Java 8 Stream dispatch data to other methods?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Pre Java 8, we have all seen code like this:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> someList = ....
for (Pair<A, B> item : someList) {
    A leftItem = item.getLeft();
    aMethodThatProcessesTypeA(leftItem);
}
```

Seems like it should be simple/trivial to do via a Stream:

```
someList.stream()
        .map(i -> i.getLeft())
        .???
```

However, now I get stuck - with Streams being lazy, I am not sure how to proceed.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: `.forEach((leftitem) -> aMethodThatProcessesTypeA(leftitem)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
someList.stream()
        .map(Pair::getLeft)
        .forEach(this::aMethodThatProcessesTypeA);
```

assuming the method `aMethodThatProcessesTypeA()` is defined by the same instance as the method running your *Java 8 Stream Code* shown above.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I missed in the java doc that forEach was a terminal operation.  It is there plain as day and this is new enough to me that I didn't know that yet.  Won't forget now though!